# Perl use argument to create path

Tags: perl, parameters

I am given a parameter while the Perl script is called and I would like to use that parameter to create a path for my logs.

I call the Perl script like this:

```
./hello.pl GERMANY
```

And I would like to use the first parameter to create the log path, something like this:

```
my $country= shift @ARGV;
my $name_of_log='/usr/log/{$country}/hello.log';
```

How would I go about doing this in Perl?

Comment: `my $name_of_log="/usr/log/$country/hello.log";` should do it. Your example doesn't work because [single quotes mean no interpolation](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Quote-and-Quote-like-Operators).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should do:

```
my $name_of_log = "/usr/log/" . $country . "/hello.log';
```

Of course, you may want to run some sanity checks on it, such as ensuring it's not able to "escape" from the `/usr/log` area by using `..`, for example.